# Android called on an uninitialized AudioRecord Error

Tags: android, user-permissions, audiorecord

I was working on an API that get some information from a device connected to the audio jack, but when i tried to debug my app on an ASUS MEMO Pad 7 (with android 4.3) i get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.walker.integration.WalkerService@21a3f7e0 with Intent { cmp=mx.com.mitec.testmit/com.walker.integration.WalkerService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2877)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1452)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5406)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
            at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:537)
            at com.bbpos.emvswipe.k.b(SourceFile:73)
            at com.bbpos.emvswipe.EmvSwipeController.startAudio(SourceFile:3410)
            at com.walker.integration.WalkerService.initEmvSwipeController(SourceFile:61)
            at com.walker.integration.WalkerService.onStart(SourceFile:96)
            at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2860)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1452)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5406)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
```

Someting thad doesn't happens when i tried to run it on my phone Moto G (with android 4.4), i don't know whats happening or how to solve it.

I look to my manifest to see if i put the permisions or i put the wrong minsdkversion, but it isn't the problem.

Here is my manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"/>


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The error should describe the problem exactly. The AudioRecord object wasn't initialized and you called startRecording on it.

To initialize the AudioRecord object, try

```
audioRecordObj = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, sampleRate, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);
```

where `

```
int sampleRate = 8000; //Hz
int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT; 
int bufferSize = 60000;
```

just as an example. See more in [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#AudioRecord(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).